# Custom collection view cell: content under margin height not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have created one custom collection view cell. Inside the xib I have kept all the contents under the cell's view. The problem is that I need to have one underline like marking on my cell, by now all my subviews that are not leaving a minimum margin of 8 pixels from all directions within the cell, are getting clipped.

I have tried a couple of things.

1. I have added the contents inside the cell's view itself other than its content view.

[image]

2. I have tried unchecking the 'clips subview' flag of the collection view cell.

Comment: can you please  upload screenshot if you dont have any issue?

Comment: I am sorry I can't.. There are only 2 subviews.. one MainView which is leaving margin of 8 pixels from all the four directions. And another one (which is not visible) 'UnderlineView', this is constraint'd to the bottom corners of the cell with a 1 pixel height. This doesn't show up unless I make a margin of 8 pixels between the underline view's bottom and the custom cell's view.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly apply following constraints to get your desire output.

Step 1 : Constraint for `MainView`.

[image]

**Step 2** : Constraint for `UnderlineView`.

[image]

And Output :

[image]

Hope this help you.

Comment: This is how I did it.. but the contents below the bottom 8 pixel seems invisible..

Comment: @Gokul, is there any margin left between mainView to UICollectionVIewCell in your output?

Comment: Yes there an 8 pixel gap